# Emulator Error : x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration, dunno what i can do

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, haxm

I use VSCode for Flutter.
When start debugging I get this error:

> Failed to launch pixel: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently
>   requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly
>   installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed
>   on this machine

and 
C:\user(Username)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extra\intel

I found out intelhaxm-android.exe but it can't install.

What should I do?

Comment: what version of android did you install? There was a problem with latest versions.

Comment: after ask this question, I can fix it! Thank you for your answer. First, In BIOS mode, I turned on VT-X. Second, In Windows Features On or Off, I turned off Hyper-V. And then, I re-installed haxm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install it through Android Studio SDK Manager.
You can as well follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows) to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: after ask this question, I can fix it! Thank you for your answer.
First, In BIOS mode, I turned on VT-X.
Second, In Windows Features On or Off, I turned off Hyper-V.
And then, I re-installed haxm.